# How is a exploit code mmaped in user space executed in kernel space?

Tags: ubuntu, cve, kernel

I am reading about a Ubuntu-12.10 security exploit `CVE-2013-1763` which describes the vulnerability of stack buffer overflow that can be exploited to escalate privilege of a process and gain `root` access.

The hardcoded exploit is given on the link:
https://github.com/spinlockirqsave/examples/blob/master/hacker/ubuntu_cred/main.c

I have a couple of questions regarding the same:

1. How was `sdiag_family=0x37` decided ?
2. What is the exact control flow, how does the privilege escalation code `x()` which is mmaped in user space executed once the socket request has been sent ?
3. Is there any relation between the `sdiag_family=0x37` and `mmap_start=0x1a000` values ?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [affected code](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/core/sock_diag.c?v=3.7) (from kernel 3.7.0, lines 115 to 132):

```
static int __sock_diag_rcv_msg(struct sk_buff *skb, struct nlmsghdr *nlh)
{
        int err;
        struct sock_diag_req *req = nlmsg_data(nlh);
        const struct sock_diag_handler *hndl;

        if (nlmsg_len(nlh) < sizeof(*req))
                return -EINVAL;

        hndl = sock_diag_lock_handler(req->sdiag_family);
        if (hndl == NULL)
                err = -ENOENT;
        else
                err = hndl->dump(skb, nlh);
        sock_diag_unlock_handler(hndl);

        return err;
}
```

The `sock_diag_lock_handler()` function is accessed with the `req->sdiag_family` value as index. The index comes from the userland. The called function code is:

```
static const inline struct sock_diag_handler *sock_diag_lock_handler(int family)
{
        if (sock_diag_handlers[family] == NULL)
                request_module("net-pf-%d-proto-%d-type-%d", PF_NETLINK,
                                NETLINK_SOCK_DIAG, family);

        mutex_lock(&sock_diag_table_mutex);
        return sock_diag_handlers[family];
}
```

So we see that the provided index is used directly to access an array called `sock_diag_handlers[]`, without any check on the array length. The array contains 40 elements, but the index in the exploit is 0x37, i.e. 55 -- so the code reads bytes which are 16 entries past the array end (i.e. 128 bytes, since each entry is a pointer and the exploit is apparently meant for a 64-bit machine).

The returned value is used by the caller (`__sock_diag_rcv_msg()`) as a pointer to a structure, that contains, in particular, a field called `dump()` which is a function pointer -- and the code *invokes* that function by following the pointer.

The exploit relies on the presence, in the kernel memory space, of a suitable pointer at offset 55 of the array (not part of the array, but of some other data which just happens to be there). That pointer points to a benign and normal structure within the kernel space, that is meant for something completely different; but the faulty code will *interpret* that structure as a `struct sock_diag_handler` and read what it assumes to be the `fault` field, which happens to contain the value 0x1A000. So the code will "jump" to that address.

All that remains for the exploit is to make sure that there is executable code at the 0x1A000 address. That address is part of the user space; the userland exploit can reserve that space with a `mmap()` call, and put some code in it. Here, codes that makes the currently executing process "root".

The important point to understand is that "user space" and "kernel space" coexist. When a process it executing, it "sees" memory as a collection of pages, some of which being mapped to actual RAM. The "kernel space" is a subset of these pages. The mapping is done with the [MMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit), and it enforces access rights: when the code that executes has "user privileges" (as opposed to "kernel privileges"; we are not talking about root vs non-root here), any attempt at accessing pages that are marked as "kernel space" will trigger an exception (segfault). When the process performs a system call (e.g. the `send()` call), it jumps into kernel space and temporarily acquires kernel privileges, at which point all the kernel space becomes reachable. But the mapping of pages has not changed; the user land pages are still there, and, crucially, while user privileges are not sufficient to access kernel pages, kernel privileges are more than enough to access user pages. Therefore, nothing prevents code with kernel privileges to jump into code that happens to be in user space. This is what happens here.

So the exploit control flow is:

- Process sets up its special code at address 0x1A000.
- Process performs a `send()` system call with some parameters which lead to execution of `__sock_diag_rcv_msg()` in kernel space, with kernel privileges.
- That function erroneously follows what appears to be a function pointer (but is not), and jumps into code at address 0x1A000. That code is in user space (i.e. it was built by the exploit with a perfectly legitimate `mmap()` call), but executes with kernel privileges.
- That exploit code uses the kernel privileges to change the current "identity" of the executing code. That identity (UID) is simply a value in some table in kernel space; since the code has kernel privileges, it can simply change the UID to 0, which means root.
- The exploit code returns, so execution gets back to `__sock_diag_rcv_msg()`, who is very happy about the whole proceedings, and returns. Ultimately, the system call terminates, and the user land process regains control, with user privileges.
- However, the kernel now thinks that the process runs as root. The exploit code simply launches a shell with these newly acquired privileges.

The 0x37 and 0x1A000 are simply values that "work well" in the case of the specific kernel version that the exploit is tailored at: the attacker noticed that in the kernel space, 128 bytes after the overflown array, there was a pointer to a kernel-space structure whose pseudo-`dump` field contains a value that, interpreted as a pointer, points to an address which is low enough to be in reach of a normal userland `mmap()`. The data we are talking about here (the overflown array and the structures that follow it in RAM) are part of the "constant data" segment: these are normal, constant data structure filled when the kernel was compiled. Thus, they may change when a new kernel is compiled, but all instances of the affected kernel will be identical in that respect -- which is why the exploit is specific to a kernel version (here, the one shipped with Ubuntu 12.10 in 64-bit mode), but will work on all systems that use that kernel.

Other affected kernel versions, or other compilations with distinct options, may need different values for the `sdiag_family` and `mmap_start`, but the conditions on a suitable structure are not hard and chances that there are many other appropriate combinations. (Or at least there *were*, since the kernel has now been fixed in that respect, and won't do any access past the array end, which avoids the whole issue.)

Comment: Shouldn't the SMAP/SMEP features of the kernel have stopped the kernel from executing the user land code ? Also just for clarification, `The 0x37 and 0x1A000 are simply values that "work well"...` does this mean that the exploit can be replicated for this particular kernel version with only this set of values and that there is no particular mathematical relation as to how those were found, rather just based on exploiter's observation ?

Comment: The code is made executable by using the `PROT_EXEC` flag of the mmap call.

Comment: @bawejakunal you are definitely right.   This is ret2usr exploitation technique and definitely require that SMEP be disabled, or not available in the specific hardware.